# Magento2: How to Import and export CSV file from admin panel?

Tags: magento2, csv, importexport

How to import and export custom CSV file from admin panel demo?

I want to add the custom shipping price state and zip code wise in the database from the admin panel. Then I will apply extra the shipping charges on the cart page.

My Magento v2.0.17

Comment: product csv want to import export?

Comment: No, I need to custom CSV file upload in the database. @RohanHapani

Comment: Please explain more or add screenshot here.

Comment: I want to add the custom shipping price state and zip code wise in the database from the admin panel. Then I will apply extra the shipping charges on the cart page. @RohanHapani